# Eloquent query on tables with relationships and a condition in a pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I've various tables with these relationships, described as models

Customers

```
class Customers extends Model
{    
  public function claims()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Claims::class);
  }
}
```

Claims

```
class Claims extends Model
{    
  public function refunds()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Refunds::class);
  }         
        
  public function customers()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Customers::class,'customers_id');
  }           
}
```

Refunds

```
class Refunds extends Model
{    
  public function services()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Services::class)
      ->withPivot(['services_id','services_amount','services_status']);
  }     
        
  public function claims()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Claims::class,'claims_id');
  }           
}
```

Services

```
class Services extends Model
{
  public function refunds()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Refunds::class);
  }
}
```

I need to do a query that return all rows from Customers with a row count on the pivot table refunds_services where services_id = 1 for each Customers row.

How can I do this? Is it possible? or better i use query builder and sql with several joins

Thx

Answer (score 2):

you can try :

```
Customers::select('cliente')
    ->addSelect([
        'countRefundService' => Customers::withCount('claims.refunds.services', function($query) {
          $query->where('id', 1);
        })->get();
      ])
    ->whereHas('claims.refunds.services', function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', 1);
    } )
    ->get();
```

Comment: yes, but if i have for example in the cross table refunds_services two rows with services_id = 1 i wanted to have two rows as query result because My real intent was to have a normal pivot table that count for each "Cliente" how many rows of services_id = 1......

Comment: So the result should be the customer row + a count of how many service_id = 1 ?

Comment: Yes a pívot tablet with cliente field in customer table and a count of service_id equal 1 related to that cliente . Possible?

Comment: just change my answer, can you try it ?

Comment: it gives me this error    mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given